# Still timeout receiving message from renderer

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-chromedriver

There still seems to be a problem with Eclipse, Chrome, Chrome Driver, Java and Selenium.
Still getting "Timeout receiving message from renderer".
The solutions offered in Stack Overflow are that Chrome and Chrome Driver do not match (both using 96), or Selenium is old (we have the latest) or java is old (we have 8).

Is anyone else still getting this error?  Most of the time it is just annoying, but sometimes it causes a timeout exception.  Any other suggestions.

Here is one place it happens, switching to the frame:

```
private void switchToBaseFrame() {
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    driver.switchTo().frame(baseFrame);
}
```

Can I put a try/catch around it and ignore it?  Not sure that would help:

```
private void switchToBaseFrame() {
    driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
    try {
         driver.switchTo().frame(baseFrame);
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
         // ignore
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are sure that your driver fits on your chrome version, clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: It gets completely rebuilt each run starting from the git checkout, mavening, etc, into a blank workspace

Comment: Do you run the test in docker image?

Comment: What type is `baseFrame`?